# OpenX Admin not accessible

Tags: openx

My OpenX server got slammed with heavy traffic a couple of days ago. Since then I have been unable to get into the OpenX admin. The page just times out. The server is still delivering ads. Apache had been restarted and the RAM on the server cluser has been increased from 256MB per server (896MB total) to 512MB per server (1.6GB total). I'm seeing lots of apc-cache 'Unable to allocate memory for pool' errors in the logs.

Server is running 1ubuntu4.15 with PHP 5.3.2. OpenX version is 2.8.9
PHP settings
memory_limit=64M
max_execution_time=90

Any advice on where and what to look at?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the Admin UI working again by removing all files in the OpenX cache folder.