# OpenX Admin not loading

Tags: php, openx

I have two openx 2.8 servers running here. The issue is that trying to open the admin page redirects me to the full path www.myserver.com/www/admin/index.php with blank screen. Still I can access www.myserver.com/www/images/, delivery etc. I tried a lot of stuff without any success. 
this one doesn't work for me [OpenX Admin not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652467/openx-admin-not-accessible/38226061#38226061)

Comment: Blank screen: Check for errors. Post "your" code and not *"this one doesn't work for me `<link>`"*.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen to me last week. Check your configuration file in the /var folder of your openx installation, probably called something like www.yoursite.com.conf.php. Mine was corrupted. I suspect outside malicious activity, especially since [there are known vulnerabilities in OpenX.](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-9088/Openx.html). I'm currently looking at upgrading to Revive Ad server, which is the successor and is supposed to offer a complete upgrade path.

Comment: I just upgraded it to Revive. Everything is working perfectly now

Comment: Glad to hear it. Did you have any issues with the upgrade?

Comment: nope you just have to copy youradserver.conf.php from var folder of openx to var folder of Revive and it will start upgrade instead of clean install.